# How to stop processing if observable is empty or null

Tags: java, rx-java, observable

I am trying rxJava. I have a chain of operators which process the `Observable` returned from a service.

I want to do nothing when the returned `Observable` is empty (`Observable.empty()`).

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: Add some code please.

Comment: When the returned value is an empty observable your doOnNext will never be executed, hence - you would do nothing. So you have already achieved doing nothing by returning Observable.empty()

Answer (score 0):

By its very nature, an `Observable` that emits no values and then completes (which is what `Observable.empty()` does) will pass no values to your subscriber or any downstream step of your chain.

```
Observable<String> observable = Observable.empty();
observable
  .map( value -> "Value " + value )
  .doOnNext( value -> logger.info( "Value is " + value )
  .subscribe();
```

If you execute the above code, nothing will be logged and no mapping of values will occur.

On the other hand, if you meant an observable that doesn't emit any values and never completes (which is what `Observable.never()` does), that is a bit more complicated. You will have to introduce a timer that emits an error on timeout, thus completing the observer chain.

```
Observable<String> observable = Observable.never();
observable
  .map( value -> "Value " + value )
  .doOnNext( value -> logger.info( "Value is " + value )
  .timeout( 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS ) // (1)
  .onErrorResumeNext( Observable.empty() ) // (2)
  .subscribe();
```

Line marked with (1) is where the timeout is applied, and the line marked with (2) is where the empty stream is used to cause the observable chain to terminate.